# Rebuild Index on table with 128 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, indexing, rebuild

I have a database table with over 128 million rows.

The issue I have to deal with is the indexes, the database performs very bad over time, I put it down partly to the indexes getting fragmented. One of the current indexes on the large table is around 50% Total fragmentation.

Reorganizing did about 1% in 1 hour so it would take way too long.

On such a large table, a re-index can take as much as 5 hours if not more, and I haven't found a real way of monitoring progress. What would be the best and quickest way to re-build an index on such a large table? Should I set the database as "OFFLINE" ?

The database also runs a very large and busy website, so I've scheduled a maximum of 6 hour downtime to get this done but need the quickest and best way possible to do this.

I also need to update all other indexes on the database, but this table is the hardest one.

Comment: Have you actually measured a significant performance improvement from rebuilding the index, by analyzing before and after performance? If so, what is the OLTP performance difference between a fresh index and a 50% fragmented one? Oftentimes DBAs rebuild indexes just because they think it should be done. Indexes are designed to have some "bloat/fragmentation" in them and trying to defrag them constantly can often be futile.

Comment: In all honesty, I haven't done a true performance tests between new index and an old one, all I know is that often after doing it, the slow queries and reports we run on our system get a lot faster. A re-build or re-organize hasn't been done in over 1 year on this table. I'm not aware of the term OLTP, sorry!

Comment: @Aki: OLTP = Online Transaction Processing.  An OLTP workload is characterized by a large number of small read and a mix of read/write, such as is typical of a database serving a website.  You might consider just updating statistics (which an index rebuild does too).  Stale stats can result in suboptimal execution plans and thereby slow performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you havent measured the following 2 things on this particular index, you probably don't yet have a reason to rebuild.

1. How much (if any) your queries actually improve immediately after the rebuild.
2. How long the improvement lasts (ie. How long your index takes to return to a steady state of 50% fragmentation after a rebuild.

B-Tree indexes are designed to have fragmentation / bloat / free-space. Indexes often quickly return to their steady state of fragmentation. They usually perform decently in this state tend to want to return to steady state.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have this kind of information at hand as we haven't record previous results from past re-builds. Is there any way to find out if a re-index is even required without previous results?

Comment: You have to measure query times. This is exactly my point. You are committed to a hugely expensive operation without proof of its benefits. You should write some test queries and time them, before and after. There is plenty of information on Google on how to profile queries.